# spring async task get the que usage before calling

Tags: spring-boot, threadpoolexecutor, spring-async

I am using async task for some big request processing, my details are below

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfiguration 
{
    @Bean(name = "asyncExecutor")
    public Executor asyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("AsynchThread-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}


@Service
public class AsyncService {
    @Async("Executor")
    public void  processData(User user) throws InterruptedException 
    {

        /* my business logic for each user*/

        return  ;
    }

}
```

Here I am getting users list, it may contain 50 users, so before posting to async task I want to know I have sufficient que capacity to hold 50 threads, if no I have to return to caller saying my server is busy.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void postAllUsers(@RequestBody List<User>  users) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException 
    {

        for (List<User> user: users) 
    {
        try {
            service.processData(user);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }
```

So how to get current que usage ?